# batch file only runs properly from C: drive

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I have the following batch file which creates a network share using cmd as admin. When run from any directory on the c: drive it opens 2 command prompt windows and waits for the user to press a key. When run from any other drive however, it quickly flashes 2 command prompt windows, dissapears, and does not run the command. How can I make it work from any drive?

```
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin
::-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"="
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
::--------------------------------------

::ENTER YOUR CODE BELOW:
net share sharename=C:\tada /grant:everyone,FULL

echo ...
echo ...
echo PLEASE CHECK ABOVE IF SHARE WAS SUCCESFUL. YOU MAY NOW CLOSE THE WINDOW(S)
echo ...
echo ...
pause
```

**Update:**

Running it from any subdirectory in `C:` works. Running it from `G:` works. Running it from `G:\Users\myname\Documents\couple_more_subfolders` does not work

Comment: seems identical to what this guy is describing. Can't figure out where to add /D though https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/313492-batch-file-only-works-certain-directory.html

Comment: Well, at the very least you could probably replace the VBS bit with PowerShell. Trivially, `powershell -c start -verb runas "%0"` would do it without needing a temp file. Not too sure that'd solve your problem though.

Comment: If you actually want to check what's in the windows, first remove the `@echo off` so you can see the commands being run. Then replace any place you call the batch file, e.g. `%0`,  with `cmd /k %0` so the window sticks around even if the script exits early.

Comment: @Bob thanks for the help. I'm afraid I know almost nothing about batch (got this script online and only made edits below the -------- line). I don't see anywhere with `%0`. Where should i put `cmd /k`?

Comment: In your case, on the `UAC.ShellExecute` line replace the `/c` with `/k`. But I'd definitely recommend PS over VBS.

Comment: ah, in that case, the only thing that shows up is 'G:\Users\myname' is not recognized as an internal........ This is the starting of the path to where I'm running the file from

Comment: well that's odd... If I run it from `G:/` instead of `G:\Users\myname\documents\longfilepath` it runs as expected

Comment: You probably have a space in there somewhere. I'd say add quotes around the `%~s0` bit but then you'd have to escape the quotes so it ends up looking something ridiculous like `^"%~s0^"`. Or was it `""%~s0""`? In which case there's not much poing of the hacky short filename (who on earth wrote this?!)... just replace `%~s0` with `""%0""`

Comment: replacing that has made no change

Comment: replacing with `""%0""` creates a popup dialog "Windows Script Host" with an error on line 2 of `C:\....\Temp\getadmin.vbs`. Error: Expected end of statement

Comment: @Bob well, thank you for the help. Either way, I found a script that seems to do the same thing without the odd bug. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another script that does not have this problem. Turns out the first one fails if there is a space in the filepath where it is located (so really, it had nothing to do with the drive letter):

```
@echo off
if _%1_==_payload_  goto :payload

:getadmin
    echo %~nx0: elevating self
    set vbs=%temp%\getadmin.vbs
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^)                >> "%vbs%"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "payload %~sdp0 %*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%vbs%"
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
goto :eof

:payload
    ::echo %~nx0: running payload with parameters:
    ::echo %*
    echo ---------------------------------------------------
    cd /d %2
    shift
    shift
    net share sharename=C:\tada /grant:everyone,FULL
echo ...
echo ...
echo PLEASE CHECK ABOVE IF SHARE WAS SUCCESFUL. YOU MAY NOW CLOSE THE WINDOW(S)
echo ...
echo ...
pause
goto :eof
```

Comment: additional note: put the filepath of sharename in quotes in case there is a space in the path